# How do I use Facebook Login and Facebook App Events in the same Flutter App?

Tags: facebook, flutter, authentication, dependencies, flutter-plugin

We are trying to use Facebook Login and Facebook App Events in the same Flutter app, but we keep running into issues trying to combine these two pieces of functionality.

First off, there doesn't seem to be a single Flutter plug-in that deals with both, which means using individual ones. At first, we implemented just Facebook Login, for which we successfully used the following plug-in:

flutter_facebook_login

It served us well until we tried add a plug-in for Facebook App Events, but we discovered that due to the age of flutter_facebook_login (last updated on Sep 2019), it uses an older FBSDKCoreKit than the newer plugins for app events.

The simple solution seemed to be using a different plugin for Facebook Login, but after trying a couple of others I get a literal cascade of dependency errors in countless other plugins we use.

So what I'd like to know is this: has anyone else successfully combined Facebook Login with Facebook App Events in the same app. If so, which plugins do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the most recent release of Facebook App Events [v0.12.0](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events/changelog#0120) and the [PR which also address you same question](https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/pull/102): it is suggesting that you might have better luck trying [`flutter_facebook_auth`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth) plugin to support both of them together.